# How to define file template for python?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I create a file with pycharm I want it to automatically have the following lines

```
from __future__ import unicode literals
import logging
from common import const

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Is it possible to do this? These are the common lines in all project files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy to do. Follow the steps:

## Head over to `File Templates` and create a new Template like so:

[image]

## Create a new file template

[image]
[image]

## Now create your new file

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oops, I seem to have coped it the wrong way, my bad. But you should get an idea of what you need to do.